# REGEX - nesting quantifiers in combined statements

Tags: regex

A last name in Hebrew can be either in an English format, which is just a regular combination of letters, like "Smith", "Camp", "Jack" etc, or a combination of two words with a space in the middle, like "Ben David", "Bar Yohay", "Yom Tov". i tried to create a regexp that allows either the first format - a last name that is at least two letters long, or the second one - a last name that is composed of two words, each two or more letters long, with a space in the middle. here is what i came up with:

### (^[a-z]{2,}$)|((^[a-z]{2,}$)(^[ ]$)(^[a-z]{2,}$))

(I know it does not allow capital letters)
For some reason it does allow names of the first format like Smith and Jerry, but does not allow names of the second one. is there a problem with the formatting of the space in the middle? This should be an easy one for regexp professionals. thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you know what ^ and $ do?

Comment: That's because you're over zealous with the `^` and `$` (beginning and end of string bindings). Your second pattern (in its entirety) should be wrapped in `^`...`$`, not around each token.

Comment: [Falsehoods programmers believe about names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify your regex to

```
^[a-z]{2,}(?: [a-z]{2,})?$
```

Answer (score 1):

You are misusing anchors (`^` and `$`). These match the beginning and ending of the string, respectively. What you actually want is:

```
(^[a-z]{2,}$)|(^([a-z]{2,})([ ])([a-z]{2,})$)
```

Further, you can simplify your expression to:

```
^[a-z]{2,}$|^[a-z]{2,} [a-z]{2,}$
```

unless you specifically need to capture groups.

Or (so you only need one pair of anchors):

```
^(?:[a-z]{2,}|[a-z]{2,} [a-z]{2,})$
```

`(?:...)` is a non-capturing group, necessary to restrict the scope of  the alternation.

Comment: Can you break the pattern down and comment it so OP has a solution _and_ can learn from it?

Comment: @BradChristie - OP seems to understand the use of character classes, alternation, and quantifiers. He seems to have been mistaken about anchors, that's all. I feel it suffices to show that the anchors are necessarily only at the beginning and end.

Comment: The scope of your anchors is wrong. You need a non-capturing group around the alternations. In fact, you don't need an alternation at all.

Comment: @TimPietzcker - You are absolutely right. I edited the solution to, not the way I would have done it, but closer to what the OP started with, to show him the difference. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks! This helped :) I didn't understand how to use ^ and $ properly.